# Displaying Message Box using .NET Windows Services In Windows 7

Tags: windows, vb.net, winapi, windows-services

We had a windows service that was used to display a confirmation message box once a user scanned their access card on windows xp but once we migrated to windows 7, that pop up functionality no longer works. Can anyone please guide me through or give me any ideas on how to proceed with fixing this functionality asap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have discovered, services now run in session 0 which is a non-interactive session. You cannot interact with the interactive user's desktop in the way that you could in XP.

You have a couple of options:

1. Call [`WTSSendMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383842.aspx) to display a message on the interactive desktop. This is fairly basic but may meet your needs. If you really mean ASAP, then this will be the quickest solution.
2. Run a standard desktop application in addition to your service. Have the service communicate with the desktop app using some form of IPC, for example WCF. When the service wants to display information, send messages to the desktop app over your IPC channel, and let the desktop app display them.

Comment: hmm...WTSSendMessage, is this function available as part of a .NET Library? if it is then it could make my life easier than all other suggessted solutions but i couldn't find any .NET library that has this function? could you please expand on it? Google didn't reveal much for me with .NET and WTSSendMessage.

Comment: You can pinvoke it. I expect that pinvoke.net will have a declaration and example.

Comment: Heffeman - Thanks mate. It has given me some direction. Haven't worked though but i can look into it deeper.,

Comment: So i have followed your instructions. when i run the application as console app, the message pops up but when i install it as a windows service, the message still does not pop up. The boolean value returned by WTSSendMessage is false and the GetLastError() message is coming up as 5. Any idea on what am i doing wrong please?

Comment: I've no idea because I cannot see your code. If you are having problems with the specifics then they belong in a different question. That said, it is well known what error code 5 means. You can readily look that up in the docs. Have you done so?

Comment: i have updated my question with the code. 5 as it says means that ignore. so windows service is ignoring the pop up message command.

Comment: No, that's the wrong thing to do. I rolled it back. You asked a question, I answered. Your edit asked a different question. If you have a different question, ask it in a new question. Error code 5 does not mean what you say. Which documentation did you read to get that idea from?

Comment: I read it from WTSSendMessage on MSDN. I will ask a new question with my code in it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I read it from WTSSendMessage on MSDN. I have asked a new question with my code in it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18732110/displaying-message-box-using-net-windows-services-in-windows-7. What other documentation you are talking about? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Documentation for the error codes. They are linked from the documentation for GetLastError. Code 5 is access denied.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows XP, Windows Server 2003, and earlier versions of the Windows operating system, services and applications run in the same session as the one started by the first user who logs onto the console. This session is called Session 0, and as shown in the following image, prior to Windows Vista, Session 0 included both services and standard user applications. 
Running services and user applications together in Session 0 poses a security risk because services run with elevated privileges, while user applications run with user privileges (most of which are not admin).This makes the services targets for malicious agents that are looking for mechanisms to elevate their own privilege levels by “hijacking” the services.

Starting with Windows Vista, only services are hosted in Session 0. User applications are isolated from services, and run in subsequent sessions created when users log onto the system: Session 1 for the first logged on user, Session 2 for the second, and so on, as shown in the following image.

More details : http://blogs.windows.com/windows/archive/b/developers/archive/2009/10/01/session-0-isolation.aspx

You can find more details -Session 0 Isolation - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Windows7TrainingCourse_Win7Session0Isolation